# Should Dto contains full information of reference object?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, dto

Let assume I have two entities are Order and Customer. So OrderDto should have CustomerId prop or full Customer object. The same with CustomerDto, should they have full list Order object or just a list of OrderId?

Comment: Depends on what you need, and that will answer your question

Comment: I need full information object but I afraid that is not a good approach.

Comment: No DTO can create without full information of entity, you can customize it.

Comment: Put what you need into the DTO no more no less. if you have a view that needs all of that data at once, you need it all, if you can lazy load the data after the fact , just use the ids. In the end you need to answer this question, unless you have a specific problem

Comment: Thanks, I think I will put full information from Entity -> Dto. Like CustomerDto will have full list object of OrderDto. Right?

Answer (score 1):

I think that it depends what you're using it for.  The DTO should be specific to the needs of the api, not the Entities.  For example if you're creating an order, you don't need to modify any properties of the customer.  You shouldn't include the full customer details, just the CustomerId.